# How to add a new section under buttons

Tags: c#, grid, panel

I am playing around with Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition and watched a video to get me started learning c#. I took that and tried to modify it, but I am lost. I have searched and poked around a bit, but I am not understanding what is needed.

I have top text in rows and columns. I can put everything at the top but then when I set the width for the bottom text, just looks "off" above.

What I am trying to achieve is to have the last row under the buttons....

so top:

```
    <Grid Margin="10,0,10,0" Height="313" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,35,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="289" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="0"/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

        <Grid Height="214" Width="1167">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="85"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="89"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="78"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="93"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="87"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Training:"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold"
                     />
 
            <Label Content="Construction:"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold"
                     />

            <Label Content="Any:"
                       Grid.Row="4"
                       Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold"
                     />

            <Label Content="Research:"
                       Grid.Row="6"
                       Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold"
                     />
            <Label Content="Healing:"
                       Grid.Row="8"
                       Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold"
                     />
```

Then the buttons:

```
        <StackPanel
                Grid.Row="16"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

            <Button
                   Width="50"
                   Content="Cal"
                   x:Name="ButtonCal"
                   Margin="10 0 10 0"
                   Click="ButtonCal_Click" Background="#FF04097E" Foreground="White"
                 >
                <Button.OpacityMask>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.OpacityMask>
            </Button>

            <Button
                   Width="50"
                   Content="Clear"
                   x:Name="ButtonClear"
                   Margin="10 0 10 0"
                   Click="ButtonClear_Click" Background="#FF04097E" Foreground="White"
                 />
        </StackPanel>
```

Then I want to add this under buttons:
...

```
        <Label Content="Const. Days:"
              Grid.Row="12"
              Grid.Column="5" FontWeight="Bold"
              />

        <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="10" 
              x:Name="TconstructionDays"
              Grid.Row="12"
              Grid.Column="6"
              />


        <Label Content="Any Days:"
              Grid.Row="12"
              Grid.Column="8" FontWeight="Bold"
              />

        <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="10" 
              x:Name="TanyDays"
              Grid.Row="12"
              Grid.Column="9"
              />


        <Label Content="Healing Days:"
              Grid.Row="12"
              Grid.Column="14" FontWeight="Bold"
              />

        <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="10" 
              x:Name="ThealingDays"
              Grid.Row="12"
              Grid.Column="15"
              />
```

...

any links for guidance on this appreciated!